# Passing a Date from PDO to MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am getting towards the end of the process of changing over from MSSQL to MySQL and have suddenly run into a road block.  I have a number of Stored Procedures where I pass a date from a form through PDO.  This works fine in MSSQL, but is now causing the MySQL version to fall down.

This is how I am calling the procedure :-

```
$command = "CALL AddThis (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stpro = $conn->prepare($command);
$stpro->bindParam(1, $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stpro->bindParam(2, $_POST['type']);
$stpro->bindParam(3, $bool1, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$stpro->bindParam(4, $bool2, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

// call the stored procedure

$returnvalue = $stpro->execute();
```

The Procedure starts as follows :-

```
PROCEDURE `AddThis `(
    IN this_date      date,
    IN this_type      nvarchar(50),
    IN bool1          bool,
    IN bool2          bool)
```

If I remove the first variable completely the procedure fires and runs no problem.  As soon as I add the date field the entire thing falls over.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *... the entire thing falls over.* !! What happens. If error, post stack trace.

Comment: $returnvalue = false.  E.g. the procedure doesn't run.  Any Inserts inside the procedure do not run.

Comment: Do not run means? Any exception is thrown? Is that caught?

Comment: Nothing.  Even placing just one command in the stored procedure doesn't work.  By removing the date variable though it runs and returns true.

Comment: `$stpro->bindParam(1, date("m-d-Y H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['date'])), PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @meda, thanks for this, but I have tried this and it returns the following error:- {Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it may not be the best way of doing this, but I have managed to get this to work (return the answers I want).

I have kept the php as was

```
$stpro->bindParam(1, $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But I have changed the SQL in statement to

```
IN this_date        nvarchar(10),
```

And then added this line into the body of the procedure.

```
SET     @datetouse = STR_TO_DATE(this_date, '%m,%d,%Y');
```

With the m/d/y being the format that I'm passing the date in the string with "," as separator.

As I said above, this may not be the correct way of doing this, but it works, so I am happy.  lol